# Circleci runs on merged branch

Tags: circleci-2.0

I have a project on github and some issues were solved already and it has merged pullrequests.
I try to intregrate project with circleci by adding circleci config in root of the project (I created a new branch and pushed it) `.circleci/config.yml`:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/circleci
    docker:
      - image: circleci/openjdk:8-jdk
    environment:
      MAVEN_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run: mvn dependency:go-offline
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - ~/.m2
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "pom.xml" }}
      - run: mvn test
```

And I get error:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# No configuration was found in your project. Please refer to https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/ to get started with your configuration.
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
Exited with code 1
```

It tries to run a job on a merged pullrequest.

How to make circlecie run builds from my new pullrequest in that I added circleci config?

p.s. I've tried to add circleci config into my main branch - it doesn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CircleCI will look for a `.circleci/config.yml` in the branch that triggers a webhook from GitHub.

This means in a PR that the config must exist in the branch, and once merged, will be included in master.

When first added via the UI, CircleCI only looks at master, but subsequent pushes to any branch (as long as .circleci/config.yml is present in that branch) should work.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your `working_directory` is set incorrectly. Perhaps you mean `~/.circleci`? By the way, people typically set the working directory to the root directory of the project, not the `.circleci` directory.

Comment: Working_directory will not affect this behavior since that exists within the config, which is not being loaded by CircleCI in this situation.   Otherwise ~/circleci is fine, and will make the checkout directory `/home/circleci/circleci`  assuming a circleci image is used.